# Retrieve Id from DB by using Equal/GetHashCode in Where clause

Tags: linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, gethashcode

Currently I'm doing the following to retrieve the ID of a stored object in the DB which match some fields of the entity MyObject

```
MyObject contract = new MyObject( some parameters );

Session.Query<MyObject>().Where( x=>x.Field1==contract.Field1 && x.Field2==contract.Field2 .... ).FirstOrDefault();
```

What I'm looking for would be to take profit of the fact that Equal and GetHashCode are overriden to do it like this :

```
Session.Query<MyObject>().Where( x=>x.Equal(contract) ).FirstOrDefault();
```

But this doesnt work.
Is there any way for me to avoid having to type again all the fields comparison in my Where clause ? I find it ugly !

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple and straight forward: These are different concepts.

The `Equals` and `GetHashCode` are C# *(application, business)* way how to distinguish objects in runtime. It is an *operator* and *calulated value* ... both of them **not** persisted.

NHibernate does not know what should be compared on the DB level.

But what is more interesting in the snippet above is this part:

```
MyObject contract = new MyObject( some parameters );
```

The **some parameters** could mean two things: 1) identifier or 2) dynamic searching filters.

In the first case we should profit form the surrogated keys / id:

```
Session.Get<MyObject>(id);
```

In the second, we'll be most likely *(sooner or later for sure)* be provided with a changing set of values. And then we can apply them dynamically.

Finally, the case you are most likely searching for is some GetByCode or GetByName. I would say, that implementing method like this

```
public virtual MyObject GetByCode(string code)
{
    var result = Session
      .Query<MyObject>()
      .Where( x => x.Code == code )
      .FirstOrDefault();

    return result;
}
```

will **NOT** make your code dirty. In fact, this method could be on a **Data layer**. So, it could have later more setings (filters by user language... etc). While the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` belongs to Entity (POCO if possible), and should not be *so dynamic*.

Comment: Yes I understand the fact that it cannot translate Equal in SQL.
You then answered nicely what I was implicitly asking, the fact that implementing method as you posted will not make my code Dirty and can be an the Data Layer. Many thanks.

Comment: Exactly! exactly you've got the point as I tried to suggest to you... the `GetByCode` is pretty suitable solution for these (very common) scenarios. Good luck with NHibernate ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Equals method, because Linq can not translate it in sql query for your object.